# Project.xml in a Androidstudio Project. Is this part of source control?

Tags: android-studio

I have problems checking out a Androidstudio Project just on one computer. On another I can start the app without problems after checking out.

So my question is. Is project.xml something we have to checkin too, because I haven't so far.

Comment: [You can probably commit it](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore#L36)

Comment: for sure. I would like to avoid side effects. I am fighting now 3 hours only with checking this project.